# SSL Client in ruby

Tags: ruby

This is the example code from Ruby Docs (1.9.3)

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

tcp_client = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 5000
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new client_socket, context
ssl_client.connect

ssl_client.puts "hello server!"
puts ssl_client.gets
```

running it with Ruby (1.9.3) throws me this error:

```
try.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `client_socket' for main:Object (NameError)
```

why ?

Comment: You clearly have an undefined variable now. Examples are not always complete runnable programs, but simply examples of how you might use it in some existing code. And if I may, before go too far into ssl clients and stuff, you may want to learn ruby at a more basic level.  The reason that variable is undefined has nothing to do with `OpenSSL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define `client_socket`:

```
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new client_socket, context
```

According to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html#method-c-new):

> Creates a new SSL socket from io which must be a real ruby object (not an IO-like object that responds to read/write.

Answer (score 2):

Did you require it?

```
require 'openssl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change client_socket to tcp_client.

If you read the docs properly you would see that it is a typo.

What you are doing is passing the tcp client socket to the openssl new function.
For example, what they are saying:

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new name_of_your_socket, name_of_your_context

So in your case the name of your socket is tcp_client (not client_socket) so pass that in.